# prediction of fluctuation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

We can predict the probabilty of a fluctuation but why can't we predict when a fluctuation is going to happen ? Does that change if we changed the type of system we're working with.. for example if we had an approximately isolated system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we could predict exactly when a fluctuation is going to happen, we would not be dealing with statistical physics and probability, we would instead be dealing with deterministic physics and equations of motion. For deterministic systems such as are analyzed in Newtonian Mechanics, when given sufficient starting conditions we can (usually) predict with certainty when a particular configuration will be reached. (The exception is chaotic systems.)

Fluctuation usually means a random, unpredictable event. In non-deterministic systems we cannot predict with certainty, or doing so is too difficult. Instead we have to deal in probabilities of events happening. A probability cannot be assigned to an event without also specifying a time frame - eg occurrence within the next hour. Depending on the probability distribution, which is dictated by the nature of the processes causing the event, we can calculate the mean time between events. Provided that this is viewed as a statistical prediction, the accuracy of which depends on a large number of events being observed, the mean time between events can be predicted very accurately.

If a system is isolated the predictions are more reliable, both for deterministic and random systems. External influences are usually unknown or unpredictable, and have unpredictable effects.